# 501 not implemented OData

Tags: spring-boot, odata

I am trying to build a sorting OData service. My ODataServiceFactory implementation looks like this:
`EdmProvider edm = new SortMetaData();
 ODataSingleProcessor sortProcessor = new SortProcessor();
 return createODataSingleProcessorService(edm, sortProcessor);`

Within the EDM I am preparing the EntitySet, EntitySetContainer and adding them to the schema. When I locally access localhost/odata.svc/$metadata I get to see the metadata:

```
<edmx:Edmx xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx" Version="1.0">
<edmx:DataServices xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" m:DataServiceVersion="1.0">
<Schema xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/09/edm" Namespace="com.sudhi.learning">
<EntityType Name="SortNumber">
<Key>
<PropertyRef Name="number_id"/>
</Key>
<Property Name="number_id" Type="Edm.Int16"/>
</EntityType>
<EntityContainer Name="ODataSortNumbersContainer" m:IsDefaultEntityContainer="true">
<EntitySet Name="SortNumbers" EntityType="com.sudhi.learning.SortNumber"/>
</EntityContainer>
</Schema>
</edmx:DataServices>
</edmx:Edmx>
```

So far so good. Now if I try to put localhost/odata.svc/SortNumbers which is my EntitySet I would assume that it would trigger a readEntity method which I have redefined in the ODataSingleProcessor class:

```
public class SortProcessor extends ODataSingleProcessor{

    @Override
    public ODataResponse readEntity(GetEntityUriInfo uriInfo, String contentType) throws ODataException {
        EdmEntitySet entitySet = uriInfo.getStartEntitySet();
        URI serviceRoot = getContext().getPathInfo().getServiceRoot();
        ODataEntityProviderPropertiesBuilder properties = EntityProviderWriteProperties.serviceRoot(serviceRoot);
        return EntityProvider.writeEntry(contentType, entitySet, Randomizer.fillRandomNumbers(), properties.build());
    }
}
```

But once I hit the URL I get a 501 not implemented error. I am using a Spring Boot application and I have added my own servlet with the SpringServletRegistrationBean as follows:

```
@Configuration
public class ServletHandler {
    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean getODataServletRegistrationBean() {
        ServletRegistrationBean odataServletRegistrationBean = new ServletRegistrationBean(new CXFNonSpringJaxrsServlet(), "/odata.svc/*");
        Map<String, String> initParameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
        initParameters.put("javax.ws.rs.Application", "org.apache.olingo.odata2.core.rest.app.ODataApplication");
        initParameters.put("org.apache.olingo.odata2.service.factory", "com.sudhi.learning.SortServiceFactory");
        odataServletRegistrationBean.setInitParameters(initParameters);
        return odataServletRegistrationBean;
    }
}
```

I presume that I am missing some setting while setting up the servlet but not too sure.
Need help!!

Answer (score 0):

Solved this. I had not redefined the ReadEntitySet...